# Azure Storage gives "Server failed to authenticate the request" error when queueing a base64 encoded message

Tags: .net, azure, azure-storage

I want to enqueue a message to Azure Storage that should then be picked up by a WebJob. I am making an API call (explanation why I don't use QueueClient below), and when I add base64 encoding to the message I get the error "Server failed to authenticate the request". I know that my authentication is fine because it works without the encoding. I have tried changing the content type from "text/plain" to "application/xml" as suggested somewhere, but that did nothing.

An explanation why I'm doing what I'm doing:

Unfortunately due to some assembly conflicts I cannot use the Azure.Storage.Queues and Azure.Storage.Blobs packages in my project. Because of this, I use Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob (I know it's deprecated but it's my only viable alternative), and for queues I make a direct API call to Queue Service (nuget doesn't offer an alternative package like it does for blobs).

If I just post the message to the Queue Service, this message will not be base64 encoded (since the QueueClient usually handles this), and because of this the QueueTrigger will not pick up these messages.

Here's my code:

```html
var Client = new HttpClient();

            var StorageKey = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AzureStorageKey"].ConnectionString;
            var urlPath = string.Format("{0}/messages", Constants.AzureStorage.QueueName);
            var uri = new Uri(string.Format("https://{0}.queue.core.windows.net/{1}", Constants.AzureStorage.StorageAccount, urlPath));


                        string queue_message = $"<QueueMessage><MessageText>{Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message))}</MessageText></QueueMessage>";


            string content_type = "text/plain";
            var RequestDateString = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            string StringToSign = String.Format("POST\n"
                + "\n" // content encoding
                + "\n" // content language
                + queue_message.Length + "\n" // content length
                + "\n" // content md5
                + content_type + "\n" // content type
                + "\n" // date
                + "\n" // if modified since
                + "\n" // if match
                + "\n" // if none match
                + "\n" // if unmodified since
                + "\n" // range
                + "x-ms-date:" + RequestDateString + "\nx-ms-version:" + Constants.AzureStorage.StorageServiceVersion + "\n" // headers
                + "/{0}/{1}/{2}", Constants.AzureStorage.StorageAccount, Constants.AzureStorage.QueueName, "messages"); //url

            string auth = SignThis(StringToSign, StorageKey, Constants.AzureStorage.StorageAccount);

            if (Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains("Authorization"))
                Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Authorization");

            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", auth);
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(content_type));
            
            if (Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains("x-ms-version"))
                Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("x-ms-version");
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-version", Constants.AzureStorage.StorageServiceVersion);

            if (Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains("x-ms-date"))
                Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("x-ms-date");
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-date", RequestDateString);
            
            try
            {
                var stringContent = new StringContent(queue_message, Encoding.UTF8);
                var response = Client.PostAsync(uri, stringContent);

                var res = response.Result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error("An error occured while creating a queue message", ex);
                throw ex;
            }
```

```html
private static string SignThis(string StringToSign, string Key, string Account)
    {
        string signature = string.Empty;
        byte[] unicodeKey = Convert.FromBase64String(Key);
        using (HMACSHA256 hmacSha256 = new HMACSHA256(unicodeKey))
        {
            byte[] dataToHmac = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(StringToSign);
            signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmacSha256.ComputeHash(dataToHmac));
        }

        string authorizationHeader = string.Format(
              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
              "{0} {1}:{2}",
              "SharedKey",
              Account,
              signature);

        return authorizationHeader;
    }
```

This is the complete response object I am getting:

```js
    {StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.', Version: 1.1, Content: 
System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  x-ms-request-id: 0f1be2b5-0003-0009-2960-e5e177000000
  x-ms-error-code: AuthenticationFailed
  Date: Fri, 21 Oct 2022 15:19:22 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
  Content-Length: 710
  Content-Type: application/xml
}}
    Content: {System.Net.Http.StreamContent}
    Headers: {x-ms-request-id: 0f1be2b5-0003-0009-2960-e5e177000000
x-ms-error-code: AuthenticationFailed
Date: Fri, 21 Oct 2022 15:19:22 GMT
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
}
    IsSuccessStatusCode: false
    ReasonPhrase: "Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature."
    RequestMessage: {Method: PUT, RequestUri: 'https://mystorageaccount.queue.core.windows.net/myqueuename/messages', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers:
{
  Authorization: SharedKey efrelsblobstorage:*****
  Accept: application/xml
  x-ms-version: 2021-08-06
  x-ms-date: Fri, 21 Oct 2022 15:19:26 GMT
  Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
  Content-Length: 212
}}
    StatusCode: Forbidden
    Version: {1.1}
    StatusCode: Forbidden
    Version: {1.1}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you’ve written.

Comment: @GauravMantri I added my code, but I think the authentication part SHOULD be fine since it works without the encoding...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues with your code:

1. You're base64 encoding the entire message string including `<QueueMessage><MessageText>`. Only thing you should be base64 encoding is the actual message content (your `message` variable).
2. The reason you are getting 403 error message is because the value of `Content-Length` header is mismatched. In your `StringToSign` you're passing the length as the length of `queue_message` variable however the content length of your request body is based on the base64 encoded value of this value.

To fix this, please change the following line of code:

```
string queue_message = $"<QueueMessage><MessageText>{message}</MessageText></QueueMessage>";
```

to

```
string queue_message = $"<QueueMessage><MessageText>{Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message))}</MessageText></QueueMessage>";
```

and then change the following line of code:

```
var stringContent = new StringContent(encodedMessage, Encoding.UTF8);
```

to

```
var stringContent = new StringContent(queue_message, Encoding.UTF8);
```

You can also get rid of the following line of code:

```
var encodedMessage = Base64Encode(queue_message);
```

---

**UPDATE**

One more reason your request could be failing is because of reuqest method mismatch. [`Put Message`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-message) request is an `HTTP POST` operation however you are calling an `HTTP PUT`.

Please change the following line of code:

```
var response = Client.PutAsync(uri, stringContent);
```

to

```
var response = Client.PostAsync(uri, stringContent);
```

and that should fix the error.

---

**UPDATE 2**

This time the issue was with the content type request header. In your `StringToSign` the value was set as `text/plain` however the value sent in the request was `text/plain; charset=utf-8`.

To fix the issue, please make the following 2 changes:

Change

```
string content_type = "text/plain";
```

to

```
string content_type = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
```

and get rid of the following line of code:

```
Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(content_type));
```

after that your code should work.

Here's the code that I wrote which works:

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

static string SignThis(string StringToSign, string Key, string Account)
{
    string signature = string.Empty;
    byte[] unicodeKey = Convert.FromBase64String(Key);
    using (HMACSHA256 hmacSha256 = new HMACSHA256(unicodeKey))
    {
        byte[] dataToHmac = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(StringToSign);
        signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmacSha256.ComputeHash(dataToHmac));
    }

    string authorizationHeader = string.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        "{0} {1}:{2}",
        "SharedKey",
        Account,
        signature);

    return authorizationHeader;
}

var Client = new HttpClient();
var StorageServiceVersion = "2021-08-06";
var StorageAccount = "<my-account-name>";
var StorageKey = "<my-account-key>";
var QueueName = "<my-queue-name>";
var message = "Hello World!";

var urlPath = string.Format("{0}/messages", QueueName);
var uri = new Uri(string.Format("https://{0}.queue.core.windows.net/{1}", StorageAccount, urlPath));

string queue_message = $"<QueueMessage><MessageText>{Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message))}</MessageText></QueueMessage>";

string content_type = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";

var RequestDateString = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

string StringToSign = String.Format("POST\n"
    + "\n" // content encoding
    + "\n" // content language
    + queue_message.Length + "\n" // content length
    + "\n" // content md5
    + content_type + "\n" // content type
    + "\n" // date
    + "\n" // if modified since
    + "\n" // if match
    + "\n" // if none match
    + "\n" // if unmodified since
    + "\n" // range
    + "x-ms-date:" + RequestDateString + "\nx-ms-version:" + StorageServiceVersion + "\n" // headers
    + "/{0}/{1}/{2}", StorageAccount, QueueName, "messages"); //url

string auth = SignThis(StringToSign, StorageKey, StorageAccount);

if (Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains("Authorization"))
    Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Authorization");

Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", auth);
Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

if (Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains("x-ms-version"))
    Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("x-ms-version");
Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-version", StorageServiceVersion);

if (Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains("x-ms-date"))
    Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("x-ms-date");
Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-date", RequestDateString);

try
{
    var stringContent = new StringContent(queue_message, Encoding.UTF8);
    var response = Client.PostAsync(uri, stringContent);

    var res = response.Result;
    var responseData = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("An error occured while creating a queue message", ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

Comment: So I have applied these changes but unfortunately I still get the same error message. Do you have any other idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the updated code. Also, share the code for `SignThis` method.

Comment: Please do one more thing for me. Try to read the response of the exception you are getting. In there you will see more detailed error description. Please edit your question and include that.

Comment: Added the full response

Comment: Unfortunately changing to Post didn't do it either, the response is exactly the same...

Comment: Updated my answer and included the working code. HTH.

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much! It finally works, this has been killing me!